# what html character is this

Tags: html, character

What html character is this: >> <<

I can't remember as I haven't used it since long ago, but there used to be a smaller version of >> and << that was commonly used. Is it still around and what is the html code for it? &;

Answer (score 0):

you might like to search google for ascii characters... or try http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm

`>> &#187; or &raquo;`

```
<< &#171; or &laquo;
```

Answer (score 0):

»

«

`&raquo;` and `&laquo;` are what you are looking for I think

http://www.raquo.net/

http://www.laquo.net/

Answer (score 0):

I think you're referring to

`&#171;` for « and `&#187;` for »

Refer here for others http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm

Answer (score 0):

You mean HTML entities right?

«

```
&#171; or &laquo;
```

»

```
&#187; or &raquo;
```

Use this as your reference: http://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref

Answer (score 0):

**HTML Entities**

Some characters are reserved in HTML.

If you use the less than (<) or greater than (>) signs in your text, the browser might mix them with tags.

Character entities are used to display reserved characters in HTML.

A character entity always start with & and ends with ;

```
&entity_name;
```

OR

```
&#entity_number;
```

To display a less than sign we must write:

```
&lt; or &#60;
```

**Note:**

You can use an entity name, instead of a number, is that the name is easier to remember.